# Which version of FFmpeg.AutoGen should I use?

Tags: ffmpeg, autogen

I'm trying to use FFMediaToolkit library which uses FFmpeg.AutoGen.
And  I encountered an error `Invalid data found when processing input` when calling `ffmpeg.avformat_open_input` [this line](https://github.com/radek-k/FFMediaToolkit/blob/d327dc2f1c74c03ba9074cdc2dc3dea8d559d761/FFMediaToolkit/Decoding/Internal/InputContainer.cs#L134). I tried run in windows & ubuntu using the latest version ffmpeg, it works fine.

But when I run in Nvidia Jetson, it throws error. I tried to figure out the issue and MABYE it is because of the mismatch version of installed ffmpeg and FFmpeg.AutoGen. But somehow, I can't update the ffmpeg in jetson.

Here the libraries inside '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu`:

```
libavcodec.so.57
libavcodec.so.57.107.100
libavdevice.so.57
libavdevice.so.57.10.100 
libavfilter.so.6 
libavfilter.so.6.107.100
libavformat.so.57
libavformat.so.57.83.100
libavresample.so.3
libavresample.so.3.7.0
libavutil.so.55
libavutil.so.55.78.10
```

Anyone know which version of FFmpeg.AutoGen should I use?
Or as alternative, how to get the latest version of ffmpeg for Nvidia Jetson Nano?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you update FFmpeg in Jetson? That's the proper solution. FFmpeg.AutoGen has so far done a good job at keeping up to date with the FFmpeg releases. So just get the newest release of FFmpeg and the latest code from FFmpeg.AutoGen.

`libavcodec.so.57.107.100` corresponds with FFmpeg 3.4.8 (as shown by [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)) which is from 2017-10. If you can't update your FFmpeg then use FFmpeg.AutoGen from commit [f1fa4ed: Update to 3.4](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/commit/f1fa4ed21b80d9a9416c3bf75473941965f4f9a2). Unfortunately, you'll be missing out on 3.5 years of FFmpeg development.

Comment: 3.5 years? Feeling bad :(

Btw, I  updated using https://github.com/jocover/jetson-ffmpeg
It works now.
Thanks :)